# Converting from string to int with a function

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm trying to get a function working that converts a string to an int. My idea with this function was to collect every number in the string and store it in another string, then convert it to an int.

The function returns the value 0.

What this function is supposed to do is return the converted number. Which should not be 0.

```
int getNumberFromString(int convertedNumber, string textToConvert)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < textToConvert.size(); i++)
    {
        string collectNumbers;
        int j = 0;
        if (textToConvert[i] == '1' || textToConvert[i] == '2' || textToConvert[i]   == '3' ||
            textToConvert[i] == '4' || textToConvert[i] == '5' || textToConvert[i] == '6' ||
            textToConvert[i] == '7' || textToConvert[i] == '8' || textToConvert[i] == '9' || textToConvert[i] == '0')
        {
            collectNumbers[j] = textToConvert[i];
            j++;
        }
        if (collectNumbers.size() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (collectNumbers.size() > 0)
        {

            stringstream convert(collectNumbers);
            if (!(convert >> convertedNumber))
            {
                convertedNumber = 0;
            }
            return convertedNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up `isdigit` too!

Comment: IF the first character in the input string is not a number `return false` gets called during the first iteration of the for loop. FWIW There are a **lot** of other problems with this code.

Comment: Note in particular that you don't need the loop for a conversion via `stringstream`, and that the digits `0` through `9` are guaranteed consecutive values (this is not so for the English letters).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart `operator>>` is right here

Comment: @user2176127 Indeed. My bad - I blame this on C++ deciding to re-use an operator with a totally different meaning than C.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thanks for pointing that out for me, it makes more sense now.

Comment: Note:  Your implementation does not handle negative numbers.

Comment: You can transform the first if into: if (str[i]-'0' >= 0 && str[i]-'0' <= 9)...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just use library function ?

```
int stoi (const string&  str, size_t* idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

Comment: not all compilers in main use support this function yet.

Comment: Yep, but g++ do with option -std=c++11

Answer (score 1):

You want somehting more like:

```
int getNumberFromString(int convertedNumber, string textToConvert) {
    int retval = 0;
    for (auto c: textToConvert) {
        retval *= 10;
        retval += c - '0';
    }
    return retval;
}
```

if you need to code it, or simply use `stoi()`

Comment: I would drop the `get` prefix. `getSin(x)`, ouch.

Answer (score 1):

Your MAIN problem is that you are trying to convert the number before you have collected all the digits. You should loop over all the digits (use `isdigit` or `if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')` to avoid long list of individual digits - or, if you really like to list all digits, use `switch` to make it more readable).

Once you have collected all the digits, then convert AFTER the loop.

The statement `return false`, will be the same as `return 0;` since `false` will get converted to an integer with the value zero. So you won't be able to tell the difference between reading the value zero from a string and returning `false` (this is not PHP or JavaScript where type information is included in return values).

Comment: I appreciate the help and it makes hell of a lot more sense now, cheers.